# Junit 4.4 does not accept DataProviderRunner coming form junit4-dataprovider 2.3

Tags: java, junit4

I'm using Junit 4.4 and junit4-dataprovider 2.3 as my dependencies, but the following declaration is incompatible:

```
@RunWith(DataProviderRunner.class)
public class CustomValueProcessorFactoryUnitTest {
```

because of the following compilation error:

```
incompatible types: java.lang.Class<com.tngtech.java.junit.dataprovider.DataProviderRunner> cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<? extends org.junit.runner.Runner>
```

This happens even with junit4-dataprovider 2.0 too. Any hint?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tngtech.junit.dataprovider</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit4-dataprovider</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gotcha. According to the documentation:

> JUnit4
>
> since 2.0    junit4-dataprovider    still compatible with JUnit
>   4.10 to 4.12 on JVM 6 and above

4.4 is not encompassed.